# NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID with HSTS

Tags: sslstrip

This is strange error I am getting while using google.com on chrome browser for any website | Test done on Feb 5 2015

OS: Windows 7 32bit

https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl

www.google.com

Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from gmail.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).
ReloadAdvanced
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
..............
I could not find any solution on any forum or blogs.

Please mail if any body has solution

Comment: Hello and welcome to Information Security! Could you try to format your question a bit? Right now I dont understand what is the error message and what is your question.

Comment: Also, you mention HSTS in the title, but not in the question How is it related to that? You tagged it with sslstrip. What makes you think it has anything to do with that?

Answer (score 2):

> ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

This sounds like there is a man in the middle intercepting the SSL connection. This might occur if:

- There is an actual attack against you which tries to intercept and possible modify the traffic. Such attack can be on the network or on your local system.
- You are behind some hotspot or similar which requires you do login or accept the rules or whatever and before you have done it tries to redirect any connections.
- You are in a company which does SSL interception (many companies do this) and you did not import the appropriate proxy certificate into your browser/OS.
- You are using some desktop AV doing SSL interception (many do) and the browser/OS was not configured properly to trust the proxy certificate of the AV.